# Ensuring only distinct records are returned with DISTINCT

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given the following table:

```
date_field_one      date_field_two      arbitrary_value

----------------    ----------------    -----------------

   1/1/11             1/3/11                cheese
   1/1/11             1/4/11                the color orange
   2/2/11             2/3/11                1
   2/2/11             2/4/11                2
```

My problem: I'm not sure how to go about structuring a query using a set based approach that yields the following results:

- for each distinct date, the record with the earliest
  date_field_two value is returned

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit for new response!  The solution posted by M.Ali may be the best fit for your specific case as it will ensure you only ever get one row result from your base data, even if there exist multiple candidate rows for your answer ( as in, date_field_one, date_field_two combinations are not distinct ).  The following will return multiple results per date_field_one, date_field_two combination in the not-distinct scenario:

```
SELECT  t.date_field_one, t.date_field_two, t.arbitrary_value
FROM (  SELECT  date_field_one, 
                date_field_two = MIN( date_field_two )
        FROM    dbo.[table]
        GROUP BY date_field_one ) dl
LEFT JOIN dbo.[table] t
    ON  dl.date_field_one = t.date_field_one
    AND dl.date_field_two = t.date_field_two;
```

Comment: No problem haha, just edited my answer to accommodate the change :)

Comment: Thank you so much! And great call on joining the table back up!

Answer (score 2):

```
;WITH CTE 
AS
 (
  SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY date_field_one ORDER BY date_field_two
 ASC)
  FROM TableName
 )
SELECT * FROM CTE 
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Why complicate such a simple query by using CTE and window function?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
select date_field_one, min(date_field_two)
from yourtable
group by date_field_one
```

Comment: thank you! Do you by any chance know how I can ensure that only distinct records are returned given a second, arbitrary field, in the GROUP BY?

Comment: That field would also have to be added to the select clause.

Answer (score 0):

try this for latest...........

```
select date_field_one  ,min(date_field_two)  date_field_two
from table group by date_field_one
```

Comment: Personally, I'd use `min` rather than `max` when trying to find the earliest `X`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select date_field_one, min(date_fileld_two)  
from table  
group by date_field_one
```